# What does it mean that a tree's height is O(lg n)?

Tags: tree, complexity-theory

I've seen this definition of balanced tree being thrown around a couple of times:

*"A tree with n nodes is said to be balanced if its height is O(lg n)."*

Now, I'm guessing there's an abuse here, right? Because the height of a single tree is a particular value, not a function. So, what is it trying to say? Or am I missing something? Also, is there another definition of what a balanced tree is that is a bit clearer?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say the height is just `lg(n)`, or the complexity to traverse from the top to the bottom is `O(lg n)`?

Comment: There is no *specific* tree in sight though, it talks about general trees with `n` nodes in them. Since the number of nodes is a variable, the height cannot be some constant.

Comment: @cricket_007: Positive. Although most definitions I've read are more vague. Also, my issue with saying that a tree has height O(lg n) is essentially the same one that I'd have saying that the complexity to vertically traverse a tree is O(lg n).

Comment: Indeed, that's an abuse of terminology. It'd be more correct to speak of families of trees, or to specify a specific standard of balanced-ness with a specific bound on how unbalanced the trees are allowed to be. With a "definition" like this, it claims to define whether or not a tree is balanced, but you can't examine a tree and determine "yup that's balanced" or "nope that's not".

Comment: @harold: I don't understand. The height of _each_ tree is constant. The definition is saying something about trees with height O(lg n). So it is saying that _each_ tree either has height O(lg n) or it has not, which is my problem.

Comment: @user2357112: Makes sense. I'm honestly satisfied by this comment.